# Java method returns from an array list

Tags: java, android, arrays, optimization, arraylist

I was wondering that is this even possible? and what is the best way to do something like this:

```
    private int NotifCountBg(int countstyle) {
    return new int[]{
            R.drawable.count_bevel,
            R.drawable.count_blue,
            R.drawable.count_green,
            R.drawable.count_orange,
            R.drawable.count_pink,
            R.drawable.count_purple,
            R.drawable.count_red,
            R.drawable.count_gray
         }[countstyle];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a constant for the array:

```
private static final int[] STYLES = new int[]{ R.drawable.count_bevel, R.drawable.count_blue, 
    R.drawable.count_green, R.drawable.count_orange, R.drawable.count_pink,
    R.drawable.count_purple, R.drawable.count_red, R.drawable.count_gray };

private int notifCountBg(final int countstyle) {
    return STYLES[countstyle];
}
```

Comment: is this the best way ?

Comment: can you define "best"?

Comment: I was wondering to find out how can I optimize the code, I mean optimization.

Comment: With a constant the array (`STYLES`) is defined **once** not everytime you call `notifCountBg`, so it's more optimal

Answer (score 1):

Use an Enumeration: get rid of indexes, arrays and an-typed (int) constants.

Comment: there is an Enumeration exist for the parameter that used in the method, it's a private method and other programmers have not access to it

Comment: I mean I wonna call that method with an Enumeration

Comment: Ok, although I cannot imagine a reason for the caller having to store an int pointing to a position in an array and not a reference to the Enum value itself